# Windows 7 updates KB978601 and KB979309 fail with error 800736B3

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Everytime I try to install this 2 updates I get the same error while I've succesfully installed other updates.
I've tried to disable NOD32 antivirus and Spybot resident with no result.
I've also tried to download the updates and open with the Windows Update Standalone Installer but it ends with an error (in the event manager says that is 0x800736b3).

**Edit:** As suggested I was trying to install the x86 version on an x64 system. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

> I've also tried to download the updates and open with the Windows Update Standalone Installer but it comes up with a message which states "The update is not applicable to your computer".

Did you make sure to download the update for the correct architecture of Windows 7, i.e. x86 or x64?

Also try downloading the update through Windows Update again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got error 800736B3 when trying to turn on some Windows features.

It turns out to be the problem of pending updates (The updates that are installed but waiting for the reboot to be effective). After the reboot the error is gone.

It may not be the case for OP's problem but I just want to post it for the folks that are led here by Google :)